# CoordinatorLayout layout_anchorGravity jumps while Scrolling?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I am displaying a list of items in my recyclerView with the below Layout.
But the `textview` anchorGravity is jumping from one corner to another while scrolling.

Most of the Items are being brought to the original position after scrolling.
Why does it happens ?

How can I Solve it ?

[image]

**item_shopperitems.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/cyan"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_title"
                fontPath="fonts/Sofia-Pro-Regular.otf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach"
                android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_unit"
                fontPath="fonts/Sofia-Pro-Regular.otf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="100 gms"
                android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_quantity"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_quantity"
                fontPath="fonts/Sofia-Pro-Regular.otf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="10 x" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_singleprice"
                fontPath="fonts/Sofia-Pro-Regular.otf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="₹ 10000.22" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/submit_button"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="₹ 10000.22"
        android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/parent"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**ADAPTER**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewVersion;
        ImageView imageViewIcon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            this.textViewVersion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewVersion);
        }
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data) {
        this.dataSet = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_shopperitems, parent, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.myOnClickListener);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        TextView textViewName = holder.textViewName;
        TextView textViewVersion = holder.textViewVersion;

       textViewName.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getName());
       textViewVersion.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getVersion());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

If I have a simple Linear layout without any child also. This issue happens. So I think the issue is related to `CoordinatorLayout`

**Minimal layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/cyan"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:weightSum="4">

        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/submit_button"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="₹ 10000.22"
        android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/parent"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: try your text_price textview inside your linearlayout in your **Minimal layout** section.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@color/cyan"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            fontPath="fonts/Sofia-Pro-Regular.otf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach Spinach"
            android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_unit"
            fontPath="fonts/Sofia-Pro-Regular.otf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="100 gms"
            android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_quantity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_quantity"
            fontPath="fonts/Sofia-Pro-Regular.otf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="10 x" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_singleprice"
            fontPath="fonts/Sofia-Pro-Regular.otf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:text="₹ 10000.22" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/submit_button"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="₹ 10000.22"
            android:textColor="@color/tw__composer_white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/parent"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think your text_price should be under layout_quantity, give it a try.

Comment: Please take a look at the note!

Comment: Have you tried above thing?
if yes and it didn't help ,then why are you using coordinator layout you can use Relative or Linear Layout

Comment: Without using CoordinatorLayout, How can i make the above layout using Relative Layout ?

Comment: First of all tell me what is your purpose of using coordinator layout?

Comment: I'm using CoordinatorLayout beacuse I want to hide my FAB while scrolling the Recyclerview